# Android & Google Maps: Trouble with getting fingerprint and signing certificate

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm following the guides online here( http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html ) and i'm having trouble "Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of Your Signing Certificate".

Ive found the location of the keytool and now when i put  into the command line

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Chris.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

i get the following error

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Chris.android\debug.keystore

Can someone shed some light and help me out as i've been trying this for ages and don't know whats wrong.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Run

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Chris.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

You left out a \ between Chris and .android

Comment: yeah sorry that was just a typo. I have tried running with the \ inserted but still the same error.
For some reason its saying that the keystore doesn't exist in that location but i can see it clearly is there when i browse to that there!

Answer (score 0):

Export your android app,then the last page of the export will give you MD5 as well as SHA1

Answer (score 0):

You first must navigate to your JAVA home directory via the cmd line. Like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>
```

then you type

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

So if your username is Flanders then it will be:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\Users\Flanders\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

I will hope you know your user name. If not, you can do this:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

If you do not know where your Java home directory is check your environmental variables on you PC to determine if it was set in the PATH variable. To do this go to My PC or This PC(Windows 10)->Right CLick->Click on Properties->Click on Advanced system setting -> Click on the Environment Variables at the bottom of the window, the search the PATH variable in the User Variables.

The details to authenticate your client (including maps) is found at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth